# How does this code work with multiple buffer bound to same target?

Tags: webgl, webgl2, opengl-es-3.0

I have this webgl code

```js
const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const pointSizeBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointSizeBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointSizeData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);



gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(aPositionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointSizeBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(aPointSizeLoc, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

other things are in place and **this code works fine**, so I am not pasting the whole code to keep the code short.

I am new to WebGL and I am trying to form a mental model of things.

So my current thought process is that only one buffer is bound to a target (`ARRAY_BUFFER` in this case ), and when a draw call happens, data is read from that.

But how I am interpreting this code is that

1. when I bind the `pointSizeBuffer`, `positionBuffer` should not be bound
2. If `positionBuffer` is no longer bound and the code is still working, that means `vertextAttribPointer` is able to bind the values to attributes and even if the buffer is not bound anymore, those values persist.

Is this the correct thinking?

I tried googling a bit and I found that only one buffer can be bound at once, so this code's behavior was surprising to me, I was expecting that shaders would not get `position` data and would only get `pointSize` data because that was the last one bound.

I am a Webgl noob, so not very clear in understanding these terms like buffer, target, etc, but I am trying to go step by step.

PS **I know that we can interleave values in one buffer and I made that work** so don't suggest that. I am just trying to understand how things are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Vertex Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) binding (`ARRAY_BUFFER`) is a global state. However, the binding of the array buffer to a specific vertex array specification is stored in the state vector of the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).
Each attribute which is stated in the VAOs state vector may refer to a different array buffer. When [`vertexAttribPointer`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER`, is associated to the specified attribute index and the ID of the object is stored in the state vector of the currently bound VAO.
(By the way, the WebGL 2.0 API conforms closely to the OpenGL ES 3.0 API.)

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, I will hold on a bit before accepting an answer. 

However, I can see that I have gaps in my knowledge and have to understand this concept of VAO before I can understand this multiple buffer thing correctly.

Comment: and I added OpenGL tag to increase the reach of the question, :P

Comment: @ashishsingh The WebGL 2.0 API conforms closely to the OpenGL ES 3.0 API. So [tag:opengl-es-3.0]. OpenGL != OpenGL ES, some may downvote for this sole reson

Comment: I see, I thought because concepts are similar, someone might give some insights. I will keep this in mind for future questions.